# Excel formula to count when value changes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have an Excel conundrum I can't seem to crack.

In Column A I have a long list of counties, and each of those counties is a member of a larger group of counties that pertain to a particular funding request to our organization. In column B is the total funding amount in that request--e.g., if an organization received $3,000 and claims to serve counties Smith, Robeson, Macon, and Duplin, the spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Col A    Col B   (data starts in row 1) 
Smith    3000
Robeson  3000
Macon    3000
Duplin   3000
```

.. and the list goes on with counties from other requests, for about 1200 total row entries.

I'm trying to set up a function that allows the total amount (3000) to be divided up by the number of cells *up until* the B value changes. So, if the next B value is 6500, for example, the formula would only count A1-A4 in the denominator. This would theoretically allow me to drag the formula across the entire column, as opposed to manually changing the range every time there's a new grouping of counties. (The entries have already been ordered so that no two groupings of counties from a same-value request (e.g., two $10,000 requests) are adjacent to each other).

I have not been able to construct a COUNT formula that can account for an unknown range based on a value *change* rather than occurrence. I would appreciate any help you could provide! Oh, and happy Halloween.

Comment: I'm not getting exactly what you mean... Is it... If you have B1-B4 all as 3000, then you would want that 3000 split into 4 parts, so 750 (3000/4) is shown?... Then the next rnage
So perhaps, you can have B1-->B4 as total amount for that company... then C1-->C4 the amount for each of the counties?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a pivot table.

Comment: Suggest you provide a second set of counties with a different funding amount as well as the results that you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways to format your data. For instance, what if two requests in a row are for the same amount? You need a unique ID for each request so you can distinguish between them. However, to answer you actual question, I believe your goal is to count how many instances of the value in `B` exist in a row and then divide the value by the number of instances. To that end, I suggest the following:

1. Add a header row. You don't *have* to, but it makes the formula much simpler because you don't have to error check for when you're on the first row.
2. Use this formula in cell `C2` and copy / paste down as needed:
   `=IF(B2=B1,C1,B2/(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:B1001<>B2,),0)-1))`
   If the value is the same as the previous, then just copy its calculations. Otherwise, count how many of the same value are in a row and then divide the value by that count.
   Note that I assumed there would be less than 1,000 in a row because that should cover it.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier if you would add a column to identify funding requests. 
It can be out of sight; e.g., column `Z`.  Set `Z1` to 1, and set `Z2` to

```
=IF(B1=B2, Z1, Z1+1)
```

and drag that down to the bottom of your data.  Then the denominator you want is

```
COUNTIF(Z$1:Z$9999, Z1)
```

(adjusting the `9999` to cover all your data), and so `C1` can be

```
=B1 / COUNTIF(Z$1:Z$9999, Z1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set C2 TO `1` and write this formula in C2: `=IF(B3=B2,(C2+1),1)`

[image: Screenshot of formula]